# Get posts by category name

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, get-posts

I'm having a terrible time trying to figure this out.

I've registered a custom taxonomy (clinical-programs) and like to list all the PAGES that are assigned to particular page(s).

[image]

Comment: You want to list _Pages_, but are showing the _Categories_ Meta Box. What exactly is your problem? Please file an [edit] and be more verbose with both your setup as well as your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answering!. I was looking for a more complete solution. I figured it out.

```
echo '<div class="row profiles">';

        $terms = get_terms("clinical-programs");
        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            //View faculty member by clinical programs
            $view_by_clinical_programs_args = get_posts(array( 
                    'post_type' => 'faculty-clinical', 
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC' ,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'clinical-programs',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug
                    )
                )
            ));

            echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                echo "<h3>" . $term->name . "</h3>";
                echo '<div class="row">';
                    foreach ( $view_by_clinical_programs_args as $post ) {

                                //var_dump($post);
                            get_template_part( 'content-faculty-clinical-profiles-medium' );

                        }


                    }
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

        }       

        echo'</div>';// end row
```

Answer (score 1):

> list all the PAGES that are assigned to particular page(s).

I'm assuming you mean "particular term(s)." which would be in your `clinical-programs` taxonomy. You'll have to do a bit of coding - you need to start a [new WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and structure your query as such:

```
$taxPages = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_POSTTYPE_HERE',
    'clinical-programs' => 'acne-and-rosacea',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
) );
```

You could then add this to a [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) or you might want to even create a Taxonomy Template by copying your index.php and renameing it `taxonomy-clinical-programs.php`